# How to make url like this

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

hi i have doubt in url rewriting in Yii...

now when i open one particular food item from the list of food i am getting url `www.example.com/food/12345`. here **food is controller name** and **13245 is foodId**.

but i want to rewrite above url like `www.example.com/food/new-sweet-canada` when i open that food item for view(details). here new-sweet-canada is stand for (new or old/test/location from food talbe)...

so instead of foodId i want to show other attributes of that food from db table. i guess i have to write url rules for this.

i want it because i want to make URL SEO friendly so.

but i have no idea how to do it? or is it possible?

this is my url rules array()

```
   '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view', 
   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
   '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you make www.example.com/food/12345 works, in .htaccess or by yii itself?

Comment: i have just uncommented Yii default ulr manager code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps

```
Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("food", array("foodId"=>"$old-$test-$location"));
```

where `$old`, `$test` and `$location` contains your `old/test/location`

Comment: i want to change url buddy not db query

Comment: from where `www.example.com/food/12345` is coming

Comment: make sure to change or create the variables `$old`, `$test` and `$location`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42771/discussion-between-404-not-found-and-zzlalani)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a function which takes in $_GET variable as the label of the food, finds the id using $model->findByAttribute(array('label'=>$_get)) and then.. render the page by passing the model.

so instead of your action being actionFood($id) it'd be actionFood($label)

Answer (score 0):

This example uses mod_rewrite (put it in your htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.php/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?$1=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule index.php/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Then your information can be accessed through $_GET. You can then call your page like www.example.com/asd/qwe and for your script it will be like it was called like www.example.com?asd=qwe

I recommend to learn something about mod rewrite as it is very unlikely this example will work out of the box for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define rules for food controller separated from others.

```
 'food/delete/<id:\d+>'=>'food/delete',
 'food/create'=>'food/create',
 // ... also other food controller methods
 'food/<attr:\w+>'=>'food/view',
 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view', 
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

[Yii url management document](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) can be helpful.

Comment: i have diff methods say create,delte and all.. but i want to apply it for view only